# Sharing a Logger Between Threads of the Same Class

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, concurrency

If I have a log4j logger in a class that implements Runnable:

```
MyTask implements Runnable {
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyTask.class);
  ...
}
```

If I create many instances of this `Runnable` and submit them to an `ExecutorService` on a multi-core machine where they run in parallel, and they all write to the static `Logger`, this seems like there is a risk of contention. A better pattern seems to be:

```
MyTask implements Runnable {
  private final Logger log;
  MyTask(String name) {
    log = Logger.getLogger(name);
  }
  ...
}
```

So my question... is this a pattern you have used or found necessary as at the moment I am purely hypothesising?

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Ignoring the premature optimization issue, unless those loggers all have different underlying destinations the output is probably going to be synchronized at some level anyway (and if it's not, you have an unusable mess of interleaved output).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very typical to share a static class logger among many threads.  Typically the logger has an underlying `PrintStream` which is already synchronized, so creating more than one `Logger` is unnecessary and wasteful.